# Conky not working on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, conky

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS. Today I tried to install conky with the commands:

```
sudo-apt get conky
sudo-apt get conky-manager
```

But when I open the manager and select something, it always has the problem shown in the picture

[image: desktop screenshot]

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all
```

I've tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798999/conky-does-not-work-properly-on-ubuntu-16-04-gnome?rq=1), but it does not work for me.

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get **install** conky" etc. It's also `sudo`, not `Sudo`. Linux is case-sensitive

Comment: My mistake, i used command right this is sure not the problem!

Comment: I have read somewhere that conky manager doesn't work in 16.04. I could be wrong!

Comment: There are actually 2 solutions to the question you state you tried the solution to.  Please [edit] your post to indicate which of these you tried and what you mean by "it does not work for me". Thank you for helping us help you!